# iOS: Open Facebook native app from UIWebView share link

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-sharer, facebook-share

In my iOS Application, i have a list of weblinks which are coming from server. when I click anyone of it it open that link in a new UIWebView. In that link there can be facebook share buton or many other social network sharing button.

When I click on facebook share then it opens the facebook share screen inside the same UIWebView but what I want is whenever any facebook share button is pressed from any link then it should open my native application share thing.

How can I do it? Need help

Answer (score 0):

you can use the facebook SDK for iOS,[facebook for developers](https://developers.facebook.com),make sure to set the URLShemes in info.plist or TARGET -> Info -> URL Types, so you can open native facebook Application in your own Application